# SharePoint 2013 Online - Missing Site Settings?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-settings

I am a Site Collection Admin, but for some reason these menu items are missing from my Site Settings menu:

Web Designer Galleries

- Site columns
- Site content types
- Web parts
- List templates
- Themes
- Solutions
- Composed Looks

Site Collection Administration

- HTML Field Security
- SharePoint Designer Settings

Any ideas why I can't see these menus?

Comment: Was Custom Scripting disabled for your host?  That would cause those to not be available.

Comment: I'm not sure - how would I check?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! The setting is here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-and-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=UShttps://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-and-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 3):

As wjervis mentioned, Microsoft rolled out a feature in Office365 to limit the amount of scripting allowed in order to maintain the security and integrity of the sites in a tenancy.

When the cutom scripting is disabled, parts or features that support scripting are no longer visible.

Here is how to check:

1. Log into Office 365
2. Click the Office 365 header link in the top left.
3. Click the Admin Panel from dashboard
4. In the left menu, scroll down to Admin section and click to expand
5. Then click SharePoint.
6. In the SharePoint admin center. In the left menu, click settings
7. Scroll down and find the Custom Script section.

There are settings to Allow or Prevent scripting from running of personal or self-service created sites.  If they are set to Prevent you may not see the settings you mentioned.

You will have to determine if you want these turned on.

For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=397546

You can achieve this with power-shell commands as well.

Step 01: Open the SharePoint Management shell

Step 02: Type the below command to connect with SharePoint Admin Center in management shell. You have to replace your admin center url which is in line 1.

$spadminurl = "https://tanent-admin.sharepoint.com/"
connect-sposervice -url $spadminurl

Step 03: You will be asked to enter user name and password.

Step 04: Enter the below commands. You have to mention your site collection url where you need the sections.

$spsiteurl = "https://sitename.sharepoint.com"
Set-SPOsite $spsiteurl -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0

For more information you can view the below blog post.

http://jsuhail.blogspot.com/2015/05/web-designer-galleries-section-is.html

Answer (score 0):

The setting is [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-and-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=UShttps://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-and-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) - thanks @[wjervis](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20615/wjervis)

> Was Custom Scripting disabled for your host? That would cause those to not be available. –  wjervis

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers here. If you do allow custom scripts, it will take 24 hours to take effect. In the Microsoft documentation, it does suggest the PowerShell commands will work quicker than this but from my experience it also takes 24 hours to take effect.